# where to download bb-ratings plugin for wordpress?

Tags: posts

Does anyone have any link for bb-ratings plugin ? the one Wordpress.org is currently using for their plugin rating  (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins-plugins/bb-ratings/star.gif)

tried this link : 
http://bbpress.org/plugins/topic/bb-ratings/ but the download link does not work.

simply I am looking for a rating plugin (star rating) that works for Google Rich snippets - if you search a plugin name in Google, the result from wordpress.org are shown with voting stars (like this : Rating: 3.6 - 5 votes - Free )

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Here's the current version's files stored in the bbpress svn repository: http://plugins-svn.bbpress.org/bb-ratings/tags/0.8.5/

I haven't tried this, but I imagine you could also [download the 2nd most recent](http://bbpress.org/plugins/topic/bb-ratings/download/) and then try upgrading.